# Can I generate two similar ECDSA public keys?

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa

I am using a system that relies on base64 encoded ECDSA public keys.
I have managed to brute-force a public key that when encoded starts with a word I like.
Is it possible for me, given the private key, generate similar public keys?

Comment: Think in this direction: if one keeps doing what they have done when they "managed to brute-force a public key that when encoded starts with a word (they) like", will they succeed again? And if so, what are the odds that they generate the same public key?

Comment: Are you asking in the context of cryptocurrency?

Comment: No, I guess that for most cryptocurrency people want their hashed public key to look cool which seems like a different problem as similar public keys would result in different hashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to generate one extremely similar public key. If your private key is $s$ and your public key is the point $(x,y)$ then another valid private/public key pairs is $\ell-s$ and $(x,p-y)$. Here $\ell$ is the curve order and $p$ is the characterstic of the field. If you write your public key in compressed form, the representations will differ only in a single bit (the compression bit)!

Some elliptic curves also permit other simple endomorphisms due to their [complex multiplication structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_multiplication) e.g. curves of the form $Y^2=X^3-aX$ allow one to generate the additional private/public pair $js$ and $(-x,\pm iy)$ where $i$ is a square root of -1 mod $p$ and $j$ is a square root of -1 mod $\ell$.

For more general similarities, the ability to produce private keys from small perturbations of public keys would allow an attacker to solve discrete logarithms by [hillclimbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing), which is not thought to be possible due to [hard-core predicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard-core_predicate) on discrete logarithms.